# SVN + restricted GIT on only a part of the svn repo

Tags: git, svn, restriction

I have a large SVN repo
I'll be outsourcing one folder 'themes' to an external team who can't have access to the complete svn repo.
I heard 'git svn' would be a way to go ,
but I'm still quite new to git 
and don't have a clue on how to proceed.
if anybody has a clear use case , I'd be gratefull
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how your security for Subversion is setup. You can specify in the [authz database](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) what access each particular user has. What you need to do is restrict these two users to have access only to that one project.

Most companies don't bother with `authz` restrictions: If you have access to the Subversion repository, you have access to the entire repository. However, if you have an outside group, you'll need to set this up.

You want to look in [Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) of the [Subversion online manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) to see how to setup the `authz` database. It's not that difficult. The problem is that there are differences in the setup depending how you're Subversion repository is being accessed and whether you're using Apache `httpd` or `svnserve` as the general server. You didn't mention that in your post, so I can't give you better guidance than just saying *Chapter 6*.

---

#### What is Git?

Git is another version control system. The main difference between Git and Subversion is that in Subversion, you only have one single central repository. If you want to checkout and make changes, you must do it from that one repository.

Git, on the other hand, allows anyone to download the entire repository and make their own local copy. Others can use that local copy as their repository, or make a clone of that repository and have their own. You then pass *patches* between the various repositories to keep them in sync.

In Git, you have *checkout* and *commit* commands just like you have in Subversion to check stuff in and out of a Git repository, but then you also have *pull* and *push* which act like *checkout* and *commit* to the *master* repository you used when you created the local copy of that repository.

#### What is Git-SVN?

GIt-SVN allows those who use Git to treat the Subversion repository just like a Git master repository. You use Git-SVN to download the Subversion repository into a local copy, then use Git's *checkout* and *commit* commands to make changes. For example, these two users could use Git-SVN to make a local Git repository they can both share. They'll check in and commit their stuff to that local Git repository. When changes are completed, these users will use Git-SVN to *push* the changes back into your Subversion repository. All you'll probably see is that they check stuff out of your Subversion repository and then check stuff back in. You won't necessarily see their Git activity.

In the end, it really doesn't matter whether they're using Git-SVN or not. Your only concern is that they're making sure their stuff will work with what everyone else is doing.

Comment: Thanks David,  so if I got it right this means I need to give them  restricted svn access and let them use their common git svn repo ? would you have a sample of how I could do this ?

Comment: @user878844 - You don't have to _let them_ use Git-SVN. They'll use it anyway. Just think of Git-SVN as another Subversion client. You didn't mention how the Subversion server is configured, so it's hard to give detailed directions. Do you use LDAP? Are there groups? Do you use `httpd` or `svnserve`?